# How to pull Citrix username into Java application

Tags: java, citrix

I have an application that pulls the windows user's user name and uses that name to check against a database and provides various alerts when needed for that user name. I am needing to modify the program to be able to pull the Citrix username instead but I can not find any information on this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about how to pull Citrix but if you need  the username and if it's available according to the privileges  `request.getRemoteUser() or request.getUserPrincipal()` should work otherwise you can try

`System.getProperty("user.name")` but it will only give you the username of the user running the java process.